# Algorithm for distributing neighbour sensitive work using a graph

Tags: algorithm, distributed

I have a number of servers which deal with rectangular chunks of the world, call them "regions". When a player moves from one region to another, if that region isn't owned by the current server, all the player data has to be sent to the server which owns the region they just moved into.

You could imagine that a region is just a node on a graph with 4 neighbors (connected regions). The graph grows and shrinks so I periodically re-balance the work distribution among the servers.

I'd like to use an algorithm to distribute regions to servers optimally, taking the following 3 points into account:

1. **balanced work distribution** with regards to the weight of a node, i.e the number of players previously observed in it; if I divide the sum of the weight of all nodes, I need to hit the "nice" spot where the total weight each server handles is roughly equal to every other server in the system.
2. **contiguity of regions**; taking into account above, nodes need to be next to each other to minimize swapping players between servers.
3. and extending on (2), consider the number of swapovers from one region to another. A way of preferring that two regions are grouped together in the same server because they exhibit a high traffic of players moving between them, without breaking (1).

I've considered that one way I can achieve this is by using a crude floodfill which assigns scores to several types of region assignment "fills", but this is O(n^2) and probably isn't well suited to the task.

Another algorithm I've thought of starts at the areas of highest traffic and selects nodes with the highest crossover until it meets the minimum work threshold. This would be O(n), but could generate very "stranded" allocations of space where crossovers alternate in directions between redistribution of work, for example.

Is there another way I can assign regions to my servers, in say, O(n)?

Comment: Since it's not just abstract question, but with real use-case: do you often change your server's structure? Do you really have so many servers that it matters that adding one new node will be O(n^2), not O(n) ? Or am I missing something?

Comment: `n` is regions (ie 10,000) not the number of servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no easy and fast way split the nodes in a way which would create the optimal edge cut. Since you are planning to run it on only few servers and you know how your graph is going to look like, I think you could simply calculate the weight of a region and optimize the split so that each region has the same weight.

This should give you very good results. When running on 100s or 1000s of servers, this will take longer since you have so many regions which you need to keep in balance. Still you know the structure of your graph and should take advantage of this information.

If you wouldn't know the structure, there are several algorithms which can try to calculate an optimal edge cut in a centralized or decentralized way but none of them is what you are looking for, since it is an NP complex problem. I had to implement one on top of Giraph - [Ja-Be-Ja from KTH (Royal Institute of Technology)](https://www.sics.se/sites/default/files/pub/graph_partitioning_-_jabeja.pdf) and they compare their algorithm also with the others which are out there. So you can just see that your idea will for sure provide much better results for your problem.

Hope this helps

Comment: Interesting paper. With some modification I think it might be able to do exactly what I need. I'm still trying to figure out the suggested complexity though